# How can I reduce the impact of a long-running i/o-intensive query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, throttling, database-cursor

[This post](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Running-some-query-in-low-priority-tp2075597p2075603.html) suggests I can use a cursor to fetch from a query at a throttled rate. How do I do this?

My aim is to reduce the impact of this low-priority query on other higher-priority queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by declaring server-side cursors, with the `DECLARE` command:

```
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR select * from foo;
```

And then read its results using the `FETCH` command repeatedly:

```
FETCH 10 FROM my_cursor;
```

By sleeping between the FETCH command, you're effectively limiting how fast the query can execute.

After you're done with it, you can get rid of the cursor by calling `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK`, or `CLOSE my_cursor`

Do note that some kinds of queries cannot be directly streamed via a cursor, but will be ran to completion before they produce the first row of output. Queries with hash aggregates and large non-indexed sorts are an example. You can lower the `cursor_tuple_fraction` setting (default 0.1) to discourage the planner to choose these sorts of plans, but it's not always possible.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know to throttle a cursor is to do some work, then sleep.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_cursor()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT select * from information_schema.tables limit 5;

BEGIN

    FOR example_variable IN curs1 LOOP
        -- Other pgsql statements

        -- sleep for one second
        perform pg_sleep(1);

    END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The source code for pg_dump includes pseudo-code for its "throttle" algorithm, but just sleeping for a fixed period is probably good enough.

```
* If throttle is non-zero, then
*      See how long since the last sleep.
*      Work out how long to sleep (based on ratio).
*      If sleep is more than 100ms, then
*          sleep
*          reset timer
*      EndIf
* EndIf
```